# How to query post with custom field with multiple entries of meta_value with the same meta_key

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wildcard

Scenario:
Posts have multiple entry of values with the same key, example a single post will have multiple meta_key [drink] => meta_value

```
[drink] => "banana juice"
[drink] => "orange juice"
[drink] => "apple juice"
```

Want to find: Posts without value of orange in any entry of the meta_values with the same meta_key drink.

current method: using wp_query:

```
meta_query => array(array('key' => 'drink','value' => 'orange','compare' => 'NOT LIKE'));
```

Issue:
wp_query will still return post with meta_value "orange" in [drink] because it has other [drink] with values which is not "orange".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by doing 2 wp_query (1 to get all the relevant posts and 1 to get all the post that has the orange drink) and do an array_diff to get the post without the orange drink.

Sample Code:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'fields'=>'ids'));
            if ( $query1->have_posts() ) { 
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {$post_ids1[]=get_the_ID();}
            }
            wp_reset_query();
            
            $meta_query = array(array('key' => 'drink','value' => 'orange','compare' => 'LIKE'));
        
$query2 = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'fields'=>'ids', 'meta_query'=>$meta_query));
            if ( $query2->have_posts() ) { 
                while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {$post_ids2[]=get_the_ID();}
            }
            wp_reset_query();

$result = array_diff( $post_ids1, $post_ids2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the goofy world of [SQL wildcard searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) you need to use a value of `%orange%` with NOT LIKE.

Without the `%` wildcards NOT LIKE means the same thing as `<>` or NOT EQUAL.